# What is this Excel formula really doing?

Tags: excel-formula

May I require your help in helping me understand this Excel formula?

`=LOOKUP(REPT(""z"",255),CHOOSE({1,2},"""",INDEX(Sheet1!$M:$M,MATCH(1,IF(Sheet1!$A:$A=$A11,IF(Sheet1!$F:$F=$" & NumberToAlphabet(t_ActualStartDate) & "$8,1)),0))))`

I do not have the slightest idea what it is trying to lookup.
Appreciate all the help.

Thanks

Comment: What is the excel data? What output are you getting with this formula?

Comment: If you don't know what it is doing then why are you using it? Perhaps explain the context and you'll be more likely to get help.

Comment: This piece of code was handed over to me by another fellow classmate. I was going through it and I have no idea what it is doing. He has left the campus and I can find nobody to clarify the codes with.

Comment: Use `Evaluate Formula` from the Formulas ribbon to do a single-step analysis of the formula and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect syntax, so does nothing. For example whereas:

```
=REPT("z",255)
```

would fill a cell with 255 `z`s the additional double inverted commas (`""z""`) are not valid for use in the way you show.

Comment: @user3539844 I agree with pnuts. Double quotes are often necessary only if you assign formula using VBA.